# Is there a way to keep Guard from ever running my entire spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, guard, zeus

I'm using Guard along with Zeus and RSpec for testing a Rails 3.2.16 application. When I change an RSpec support file, Guard wants to re-run the whole spec. I really would like to turn that behavior off. I'd like to only run the whole spec by hand, and just let Guard pick up changes to my individual specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the watchers. From the default template just remove

```
watch('spec/spec_helper.rb')  { "spec" }
```

Comment: Thanks! I did that, and also the line that watched "spec/support". Tested and verified.